# Merge rows crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I use crystal reports 13 and I want the following result :

```
-------------------------------------
Com. No. | Desc | Status | Date
-------------------------------------
    1    |  a   | sub    | 01/01/2012
-------------------------------------
    1    |  a   | ack    | 02/01/2012
-------------------------------------
    1    |  a   | inv    | 03/01/2012
-------------------------------------
```

but I want to display in report as shown bellow:

```
-------------------------------------
Com. No. | Desc | Status | Date
-------------------------------------
         |      | sub    | 01/01/2012
         |       --------------------
    1    |  a   | ack    | 02/01/2012
         |       --------------------
         |      | inv    | 03/01/2012
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to center vertically the two first columns, you can simply

1. right click the fields corresponding to "com. no." and "desc"
2. select "format object"
3. select "common" tab
4. check "supress if duplicated".